# Ada - Incorrect use of "random"

Tags: ada

I'm trying to generate a random Positive in ada in my procedure. For this, I have the following code:

```
  procedure Inicialize(K: Positive) is
     package rand is new ada.numerics.discrete_random(Positive);
     use rand;
     G: Generator;
     t: Positive;
  begin         
     isInitialized:= True;
     reset(G); 
     t := random(G); --error for this line
  end Inicialize;
```

I get the error

```
incorrect use of "random"
```

I have no idea, how is this an incorrect use, or what does it even mean. Could someone please elaborate?
Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Assuming `isInitialized` is a global variable, that code looks legal as it stands. It compiles and runs correctly with a current Gnat Ada. Is the full procedure more complicated than this? Could `G` or `random` be being redeclared?

I see your earlier [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37088800/230513) which mentions a package `random`. So it's likely a name clash between the package name and the procedure name. Removing the 'use rand', or renaming the package, would cure this.

Comment: I see an earlier question which mentions a package 'random'. So it's likely a name clash between the package name and the procedure name. Removing the 'use rand', or renaming the package, would cure this.